# Android:given a current location and lat/long of places arround me how to decide which places are visible in camera?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am creating AR app for Android which would write name of places/buildings/etc over camera view when I point to places with live camera. I get my current location in lat and long, also I am able to get list of places (with their lat/long) in certain radius from my current location.

However, the most confusing part to implement  is to show only those places which are visible in camera in that moment (don't show places). One of idea was to calculate azimuth of my current location, then calculate azimuth of all places which I get in set radius, then calculate camera horizontal angle using `getHorizontalViewAngle()` and having all this parameters calculate which of places azimuth gets into this interval: `[my_current_loc + (getHorizontalViewAngle()/2) ; my_current_loc - (getHorizontalViewAngle()/2)]`.

However I think it is not very efficient way, can anyone suggest my any solution, or maybe some had similar problem and find good solution. If it is difficult to understand my problem, let me know and I will try to explain in more details.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing the right thing, but in our project we found better (performance wise) to use the rotationmatrix instead of the azimuth. You can take a look at the source code of mixare augmented reality engine. It's on github: https://github.com/mixare/mixare

The core logic is in the MixView class. The main idea is to convert anything to vectors and project them onto a "virtual" sphere that surrounds the phone.

HTH,
Daniele